# Using flex-box css to format a page header with varying element types

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to style a page header within our application using `flex` display.
Where I'm having trouble is how to set my class `device-name-test` to float right on my dashboard header.

```
<div class="diagnosis-header" [class.disabled]="headerIsDisabled">
   <div class="either-toggle diagnosis-title">My Dashboard</div>
   <div> more elements here in between... </div>
   <!-- Here is my final dev which should be floated all the way right -->    
   <div class="device-name-test">Device Name here !</div>
</div>
```

Looking at my online project here, you'll that my text `Device Name Here!` text is the final div - which should float all the way right (`flex-end`?)

https://angular-9-dashboard-flex-example.stackblitz.io/

I am trying to get a strong grasp of using `flex` display but some details are not clear.

thanks in advance.
Bob

Comment: Y u no post CSS?

Comment: @Kosh I posted the link to my stackblitz project. I thought it would be the best approach; more practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by removing `flex:1` and adding `margin-left:auto` to the last div. Like this:

```
.device-name-test {
    /* flex: 1; */
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

It's exlained here: https://medium.com/@iamryanyu/how-to-align-last-flex-item-to-right-73512e4e5912.

Comment: Bingo! That does the trick. Then if I want to tweak its position a little I can add some padding, etc. THANK YOU!